# Meaning of 'insider hiring'

Tags: meaning, expressions

there is an article about hiring. http://www.haaretz.com/misc/iphone-article/.premium-1.637980

one of the headers is 'Insider hiring'. what does it exactly mean? hiring someone you know? does it have negative connotations?

Comment: In general it's hiring from the "inside" - effectively promoting someone inside the organization - vs hiring someone who is not currently associated with the organization.  The "organization" can be a private business or a government agency.  There are many reasons why this is often a good idea, and more than a handful of reasons why it might be a bad idea, depending on the situation.  Whether it has negative connotations or not depends largely on the context in which the term is used, but it likely suffers somewhat from sounding similar to "insider trading" - something with a bad connotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to somewhat disagree with sojourner about the connotations of "insider hiring".

There are two schools of thought about insider hiring. The first is that, by hiring (effectively promoting) from within an organization, the position is filled by a known quantity, who is familiar with the values and standards of the organization. In this context, insider hiring is a good thing.

On the other hand, insider hiring by its nature prevents the infusion of new ideas. For an organization which needs new ideas (but which probably either does not recognize this or is actively resisting the concept), insider hiring preserves the cultural status quo at the expense of organizational competence. For critics of such an organization, such as disgruntled employees or stockholders,  "insider hiring" is very much a phrase with negative connotations.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the article answer it: it's to fill open positions from inside the civil service itself than hiring outside people (not already working for the government sector).And it does not have any negative connotations--- it's not like insider trading.

" One reason is that the government prefers to fill open positions from inside. The collective bargaining agreements with the Histadrut labor federation specify giving preference to current ministry employees. As a result, 53% of all new job openings that are posted within the government are internal tenders that must be filled with a current ministry employee. Only 43% are open to all comers. (The remaining 4% are reserved for employees of other ministries.) Looking out for the interests of those already working for the government does not ensure a competitive process in which the best are hired. Up to three candidates apply for internal job tenders, compared to 19 for external tenders."